# Post Form Data Between Pages with HTML Redirect

Tags: php

I have a page with a basic form with 
`<form name="myform" action="submit.php" method="post">`

The submit.php page just shows a loading ajax image and says, "we will take you there in one moment" and does some other stuff in the background.

The page then does a html meta redirect after some seconds to take the user to the final, off-domain page.

The data from the Form on the first page needs to be passed on to the redirecting URL. Since the form includes a password field, I don't want to append the data to the redirect URL.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: On submit.php you'll need to generate a new form containing hidden fields. Exclude your password, then use Javascript to post (or `method="get"`) your form to the offsite URL. Otherwise, just use javascript to exclude the password field from the URL when you are redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add the form data as GET variables on your redirect URL like this:

```
header("Location: http://example.com?password=".$_POST['password']);
```

You could encrypt the data using various methods such as md5.

If you don't want to use a GET, then you'll have to use a POST, which means you'd have to use CURL to send the data to the other page, separately to your redirect.

Comment: **`Since the form includes a password field, I don't want to append the data to the redirect URL.`**

Comment: like i said there is no other way other than to encrypt it or Post it separately